# Covariance inequality with Lipschitz functions

Tags: pr.probability

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are random variables and suppose that for all Lipschitz functions $f$ and $g$ s.t. $f(X),g(Y)\in L^p$, $p>2$,
$$
|\operatorname{Cov}(f(X),g(Y))|\le \big(\operatorname{Lip}(f)\operatorname{Lip}(g)+\|f(X)\|_p\|g(Y)\|_p\big)\alpha^{1-\frac{2}{p}}.\tag{1}\label{1}
$$
When $f$ and $g$ are the identity functions, the inequality becomes
$$
|\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)|\le \big(1+\|X\|_p\|Y\|_p\big)\alpha^{1-\frac{2}{p}}.\tag{2}\label{2}
$$
Now, multiplying $X$ and $Y$ by a constant $c>0$, we get
$$
|\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)|\le \inf_{c>0}\big(c^{-2}+\|X\|_p\|Y\|_p\big)\alpha^{1-\frac{2}{p}}=\|X\|_p\|Y\|_p\alpha^{1-\frac{2}{p}}.\tag{3}\label{3}
$$
This result seems weird because the inequality in \eqref{1} is clearly "scale invariant", that is, applying \eqref{1} directly (with $f(x)=g(x)=cx$) yields
$$
|\operatorname{Cov}(cX,cY)|\le c^2\big(1+\|X\|_p\|Y\|_p\big)\alpha^{1-\frac{2}{p}}.\tag{4}\label{4}
$$

Is the inequality in Equation \eqref{3} actually correct?

Answer (score 1):

This just looks to me like an example where fixing something prematurely (or at all) gives you a sub-optimal estimate. Specifically, fixing $f=g=\mathrm{id}$ immediately leaves you unable to do much about the first term on the right hand side of (1), so it's not *that* surprising that doing so gives you a worse form of your estimate than if you don't. Unless I'm missing something, it looks like you've deduced that your hypotheses imply that

$$
|\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)|\leq (c^{-2} + \Vert X \Vert_p\Vert Y \Vert_p)\alpha^{1-2/p}
$$

for any $c>0$ (i.e. (3)), discovering along the way that fixing $f=g=\mathrm{id}$ only gives you the $c=1$ case.

Comment: The hypothesis in (1) implies (2) and (4), and (2) supposedly implies (3). I don't see where my logic fails.

Comment: Re. *I don't see where my logic fails*, why do you think it does?

Comment: That's because (1) need not hold for $cX$ and $cY$.

Comment: Just for me (and others reading this), would you mind making your hypotheses concerning $X$, $Y$, $f$ and $g$ a little clearer? Is your hypothesis that $X$ and $Y$ are such that there is a $p>2$ such that $f(X), g(Y)\in L^p$ and (1) holds for all Lipschitz $f$ and $g$, or something else?